# on dpad right long press inside recylerview is automatically shifting focus to another view which is outside the recylerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tv

vertically I have 2 view, one is button and another is horizontal Recycler view. when I focus recycler view 1st item  and then long press D pad right, then focus is going  to the above button instead of next item inside Recycler view. I want Recycler view should not loose focus on long press.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `HorizontalGridView` from [leanback libraries](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/leanback)

```
dependencies {
   val leanback_version = "1.2.0-alpha02"
   implementation("androidx.leanback:leanback:$leanback_version")
   implementation("androidx.leanback:leanback-grid:1.0.0-alpha03")
}
```

Leanback's `BaseGridView` is suited for this kind of usecase, for fast scrolling and better focus management. Touch inputs won't work anymore